# WPF How to center the Image.Source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, alignment, center

I am developing a custom Image control in WPF .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010.

In WinForms the **PicutreBox** control has the **SizeMode** property which includes "**CenterImage**".

I want my Image control to have that ability.

Is there anyway?

Thanks

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" xmlns:my="http://schemas.sharpsoft.net/xaml" xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my1:CustomControl1
                    x:Name="customControl11"
                    Width="206"
                    Height="197"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="18,58,0,0"
                    Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My CustomControl code:

```
public class CustomControl1 : Image
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        // Bitmap to Stream
        Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Properties.Resources.webcam_background.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

        // Stream to BitmapImage
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmap.EndInit();

        // Set it
        Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Where "webcam_backgroud" is a png image added by default visual studio resource editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx) to None.

```
<Image Source="..." Stretch="None" />
```

Comment: I've tryed, but it is'nt getting the effect i would expect. By now it reduces my image a lot and put it on the upper left corner.

None: http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1783/imagestretchnone.png
Uniform: http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/2401/imagestretchuniform.png

Comment: @unexpectedkas: Can you edit your question to include some of your XAML?  The image will be drawn centered in the Image control by default, but the Image control may not be centered or stretched across its parent.  For example, if your entire window is a Grid with one Image then it will be centered, but if it's a Canvas with one Image then it will be in the upper-left corner.

Comment: Ok, I have just did it.

I setted H/V align to center and, yes, the image centers. Thanks a lot. Anyway to look it right Stretch must be "Uniform".

I was confused because the control moved on window ¬¬'

Answer (score 8):

You should try and center the whole `Image` element itself using the alignments :

```
    <Grid>
        <Image Stretch="None"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. but for some reason the control would present a kind of "thumbnail", not the original one. I'm thinking that is because of the way I am loding a resource, that is no using URIs.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
<Image Name="PreviewImage" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
       Stretch="Uniform" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="456"  
       Height="256"/>
```

Answer (score -4):

Just give an x:name on the window, and retrieve information on its dimensions.

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindowContainer"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" xmlns:my="http://schemas.sharpsoft.net
    [...]
</Window>
```

And then recall the information on the actual size of the windows from the code.Then, since you have the hosting size and the object size, it's just math. Stating a frame size all'around the background of 'frameWidth', the dimension of the image (destWidth,destHeight), you set:

```
        int wOffset = (((int)mainWindowContainer.ActualWidth - frameWidth * 2) - destWidth) / 2 + frameWidth;
        int hOffset = (((int)mainWindowContainer.ActualHeight - frameWidth * 2) - destHeight) / 2 + frameWidth;

        Canvas.SetLeft(image, wOffset);
        Canvas.SetTop(image, hOffset);
```